# Huawei P10 OEM toggle greyed out as disabled and fastboot (Command not allowed)

Tags: android, adb

I'm having a problems to which i've been pulling my hair out and not sure what to do. Essentially, I had my phone rooted, although later decided I wanted to unroot. To unroot I used an app called "simply unroot" however it did not fully unroot my device, just made it worse, my phone does not pass the safety net, however "root checker apps" suggest my phone is not rooted, although some apps recognise my phone as being rooted. My phone bootloader is unlocked, but the OEM toggle in the developer options is not set as enabled, and is NOW greyed out so i cant click it, meaning i do not have access to any fastboot commands and thus cannot flash a recovery.img. Although, believe after having trying to unroot it had automatically disable OEM.

I have tried to lock the bootloader in the hopes that OEM toggle would no longer be greyed out, but cannot do this as i dont have access to fastboot commands. Even with TWRP i cannot flash anything just promps me with Error 9. I have tried storing the UPDATE.app within the dload folder, but that doesnt work either. I have no idea how i can recover this device. Fell like i've tried everything. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

In cases like yours when fastboot stops working, only way left is to use OEM provided tool to go back to factory state. [Here's an XDA tutorial for P10](https://forum.xda-developers.com/p10/how-to/how-to-unbrick-p10-fail-wipe-tutorial-t3666659).

Other option is to flash Magisk via the no root and no recovery method.